Jupyter notebook in VS Code: Collapse all code cells
When I'm done with my Jupyter notes—the code has generated graphs and I have written my conclusions in markdown cells and compiled them to the easily readable format—I am no longer interested in the specifics of the code and I wish to collapse all the code cells. But only code cells, not their result and not the compiled markdown cells. How can I quickly do this in VisualStudio Code? Is there a keyboard shortcut, or a command that I can bind to a keyboard shortcut? Perhaps there is an extension that I can use?

CTRL+Shift+p then type collapse and choose Notebook: collapse all cell outputs. As a bonus, as for me is more useful, I figured out CTRL K + T with focus in the current cell collapses the output. Tried for v1.93.1
